Online API portal provider's parser doesn't parse the api doc(json) correctly when the request body's content type is x-www-form-urlencoded
Currently I am using the API portal service of apiable to test and publish the pre-developed APIs.
The problem is the apiable's doc parser doesn't parse correctly (the request body data's properties are not shown) when the request body's content type is application/x-www-form-urlencoded (for auth request). It works when the content type is application/json (other requests).
I have attached the relevant part of the code below.
{
  "openapi": "3.0.0",
  "info": {
    "title": "title",
    "description": "API documentation.",
    "version": "1.0.0"
  },
  "servers": [
    {
      "url": "https://developers.foo.ai/",
      "description": "Production v2.1"
    }
  ],
  "paths": {
    "/api/oauth2/token": {
      "post": {
        "tags": ["V1 Endpoints"],
        "summary": "Auth Request",
        "description": "User makes auth request to obtain auth token.",
         "requestBody": {
          "content": {
            "application/x-www-form-urlencoded": {
              "schema": {
                  {
                    "$ref": "#/components/schemas/AuthClientCredentialsRequest"
                  }
              }
            }
          },
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "$ref": "#/components/responses/AuthResponse"
          },
          "400": {
            "$ref": "#/components/responses/ErrorResponse"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "/v1/standard": {
      "post": {
        "tags": ["V1 Endpoints"],
        "summary": "Standard",
        "description": "description.",
        "operationId": "id",
        "requestBody": {
          "description": "Request payload",
          "required": true,
          "content": {
            "application/json": {
              "schema": {
                "$ref": "#/components/schemas/V1StandardDataRequest"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "$ref": "#/components/responses/SuccessResponse"
          },
          "400": {
            "$ref": "#/components/responses/ErrorResponse"
          },
          "401": {
            "$ref": "#/components/responses/401"
          }
        },
        "security": [
          {
            "bearerAuth": []
          }
        ]
      }
    },
... ...

}

Actually it works when I am using readme.com. So the problem is likely due to the apiable's engine itself but still I want to find a way to get it work on apiable. Is there any alternative way to re-write the code part of auth request?
tried to change the json data following old practices.

It works when I removed the "oneOf" property and used one schema.
Isn't "oneOf" property not supported in some cases?

OpenAPI 2.0 doesn't support oneOf property as it's one of new features added in OpenAPI 3.0.
